# MongoDB search using $in array not working

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8, and would simply like to know why a nested array search doesn't work quite as expected.

Assume we have 2 document collections, (a) Users:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("u1"),
    "username" : "user1",
    "org_ids" : [ 
        ObjectId("o1"), 
        ObjectId("o2")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("u2"),
    "username" : "user2",
    "org_ids" : [ 
        ObjectId("o1") 
    ]
}
```

and (b) Organisations:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("o1"),
    "name" : "Org 1"
}
{
    "_id" : "ObjectId("o2"),
    "name" : "Org 2"
}
```

Collections have indexes defined for

```
Users._id, Users.org_id, Organisations._id
```

I would like to find all Organisations a specific user is a member of.

I've tried this:

```
> myUser = db.Users.find( { _id: ObjectId("u1") })
> db.Organisations.find( { _id : { $in : [myUser.org_ids] }})
```

yet it yields nothing as a result.  I've also tried this:

```
> myUser = db.Users.find( { _id: ObjectId("u1") }) 
> db.Organisations.find( { _id : { $in : myUser.org_ids }})
```

but it outputs the error:

```
error: { "$err" : "invalid query", "code" : 12580 }
```

(which basically says you need to pass $in an array) ... but that's what I thought I was doing originally ?  baffled.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection.find()` returns a cursor - according to [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). Then `myUser.org_ids` is `undefined`, but `$in` field must be an array. Let's see the solution!

---

`_id` is unique in a collection. So you can do `findOne`:

```
myUser = db.Users.findOne( { _id: ObjectId("u1") })
db.Organisations.find( { _id : { $in : myUser.org_ids }})
```

If you are searching for a non-unique field you can use `toArray`:

```
myUsers = db.Users.find( { username: /^user/ }).toArray()
```

Then `myUsers` will be an array of objects matching to the query.